# Rotors bent very slightly but no rubbing. Is driving safe?

Tags: hydraulic-disc-brake, rotor

I just bought Rockrider 520 with Tektro Auriga Comp hydraulic disk brakes on it. I didn't ride it yet.

Both brake rotors have a very slight bent and no rubbing. Just nearing both pads every round and braking power seems good. (For me as an unexperienced rider.)

I did a caliper alignment by loosening two bolts, brake hard and tightening. Before this there was slight rubbing every round.

Am I supposed to do something? Is this normal? Is driving safe?

Comment: Is this a new bike or used? If it's new, take it back and make them give you undamaged brakes.

Comment: New. Bought it from Decathlon. They said that they didn't see any problem with brakes.

Comment: Then I absolutely would not attempt a repair. Either the discs are true or they're not, and if they're not then the bike shop owes you new discs. If you attempt to repair them yourself, you'll void the warranty. I would find a bike mechanic somewhere other than where you bought it and get his opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A slightly warped or bent rotor may cause some brake pulsation. The rotor can be straightened with a Park tool DT-2 truing tool. I have had good luck using a large adjustable wrench. Close the jaws around rotor and gently bend the rotor. You most likely won't get it perfect but you can get it back to usable condition.

Comment: So I will try that with a adjustable wrench. And do you think the brakes gets damage if I ride it? Before try straightening I'll do a test ride and see if brakes causing any vibration. Is it still a problem if I don't get a vibration?

Comment: If you don't have any vibration or brake pad rubbing you should be ok. If you have some pad rubbing it will wear the pads a bit sooner.

Answer (score 1):

If the rotors just came like that, complain and make them send you new ones. You are on your right to do so.

Otherwise, it is true you can successfully true a disc brake rotor, even with a normal wrench tool like [this one](http://contentinjection.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/heavy-duty-adjustable-crescent-wrench.jpg), but they are also extremely [cheap](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00MOA09N2), so it might be worth just to get new ones. You know, new is new :)